# proper way to fill js variables via ajax request

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, json

At the moment i am using the follwing way to fill my global js variables with data which is obtained by json:

```
var tranlationJson =
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "translation.xml",
    contentType: "text/xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (dataSource) {            
            tranlationJson=ToJasonParser(dataSource);
    }
});
```

Is there a more clever way? I need those variables filled because in the scrips which are loaded later i use their content.

Comment: That won't work; it's asynchronous.  Use promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make tranlationJson an object instead of variable like this:

```
var tranlationJson = {
    init: function(){
              $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "translation.xml",
                  contentType: "text/xml",
                  dataType: "xml",
                  success: function (dataSource) {            
                      this.data = ToJasonParser(dataSource);
                  }
              });
}
```

then call `init` function like this:

```
tranlationJson.init();
```

then you can access `Json response data` like this:

```
tranlationJson.data.something;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/77RRR/)

Comment: so what's the right way then? i'm not sure many of us know how to use promises and i'd appreciate if you add an answer explaining it.